# Binary representation of digits

Tags: matlab, neural-network

I want to represent any digit in 8*12 matrix as a sample
**4** be equal

00000000
00000000
00000000
00001000
00011000
00101000
01111110
00001000
00001000
00000000

do you have any suggestion of how or where can I get all digits without I spend time to make them .

**appreciate any help**
tnx

Comment: I highly doubt the existence of any method to do this that could possibly require less time than doing 10 numbers manually.

Comment: @Aioros do you konw with which keyword I can found it in net?

Comment: I'm sorry, but you probably can't. I think you should do it manually if you care about time at all.

Comment: One alternative to doing it manually would be to create 10 images, each containing a single number, followed by thresholding each image so that you get 1's wherever the image was black. This is very likely to take you longer to implement than to type out the digits manually.

Answer (score 2):

finnaly I do it manually , left this for future,maybe achive somebody need :(

```
p=cell(1,10);    
p{10}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{1}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 1 1 0 0 0;
0 0 1 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 1 1 1 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{2}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{3}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{4}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 1 0 0;
0 0 0 1 0 1 0 0;
0 0 1 0 0 1 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 1 0 0;
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
1 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1;
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{5}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{6}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{7}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 1 0 0;
0 0 0 0 1 0 0 0;
0 0 0 1 0 0 0 0;
0 0 1 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{8}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
p{9}=[
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 1 0;
0 1 1 1 1 1 1 0;
0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0;
];
```

Answer (score 2):

Note that font design started out with these problems, digitized approximations of letters. Finding readable digits with such a coarse representation will be difficult.

Even if you could find a solution by computer solution, it would surely need to be hand tuned for good looks. And for only a few digits, just do it entirely by hand and be done with it.

Answer (score 1):

You can use bitmap font editor like 'CV_fonted.exe' from
https://forum.crystalfontz.com/showthread.php?3619-Bitmap-font-editor-for-graphic-LCD

Then save as ANSI C format. After some process on the file, you can get your result.